# How to let user save updated details with the same email and mobile number he/she had registered with?

Tags: ajax, spring-boot, jsp

I am relatively new to spring boot and need some guidance for this crud application I am trying to create. This is my JSP file that works as both as save and edit form, the issue is I have setup an ajax that won't let user use the same email and mobile that is already stored in the database, but when an existing user would try to update details, the details are not being updated and stored because the ajax is not letting data pass through because of same email and mobile already stored in the database.

```
    <c:if test="${customerform.id eq customer.id}"><h2>Add customer</h2></c:if>
        <c:if test="${customerform.id > 0}"><h2>Edit customer</h2></c:if>
            <form:form id = "CustomerForm" modelAttribute="customerform" method = "POST" action="${addURL}" cssClass="form">
                <form:hidden path="id" />
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="required"><b>First Name :</b></label>
                    <form:input path="firstName" type="text" id="firstName" cssClass="form-control" name="firstName" required="required"/>
                </div>  
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="required"><b>Last Name :</b></label>
                    <form:input path="lastName" type="text" id="lastName" cssClass="form-control" name="lastName" required="required"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="required"><b>Date Of Birth :</b></label>
                    <form:input path="dob" type="date" cssClass="form-control" name="dob" required="required"/>
                </div>  
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="required"><b>Mobile :</b></label>
                    <form:input path="mobile" type="tel" cssClass="form-control" name="mobile" required="required"/>
                    <span id="mobileMsg"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="required"><b>Email :</b></label>
                    <form:input path="email" type="email" cssClass="form-control" name="email" required="required"/>
                    <span id="emailMsg"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="required"><b>Age :</b></label>
                    <form:input path="age" type="text" cssClass="form-control" name="age" required="required"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="required"><b>Gender :</b></label>
                <div class="form-check">
                    <form:radiobutton path="gender"  class="form-check-input" name="gender" id="male" value = "0"/>
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="male">Male</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check">
                    <form:radiobutton  path="gender" class="form-check-input" name="gender" id="female" value = "1"/>
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="female">Female</label>
                </div>
                </div> 
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="required"><b>Address 1 :</b></label>
                    <form:input path="address1" type="text"  id="cap"  cssClass="form-control" name="address1" required="required"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label><b>Address 2 :</b></label>
                    <form:input path="address2" type="text" id="cap" cssClass="form-control" name="address2" />
                </div>
                    <c:if test="${customerform.id eq customer.id}">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Add Customer</button>
                    </c:if>
                    <c:if test="${customerform.id > 0}">
                        <button type="submit" id="success" class="btn btn-success">Save changes</button>
                    </c:if>
            </form:form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

here is ajax :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#CustomerForm").validate({
        rules: {
            'firstName': {
                required: true
                },
            'lastName': {
                required: true
                },
            'dob': {
                required: true
                },
            'mobile': {
                required: true,
                digits: true,
                maxlength: 10,
                    remote: {
                        url: window.location + "checkmobile",
                        type: "get",
                    },
                },
            'age': {
                required: true,
                digits: true
                },
            'email': {
                required: true,
                email: true,
                    remote: {
                        url: window.location + "checkemail",
                        type: "get",
                    },
                },
            'gender': {
                required: true
                },
            'address1': {
                required: true
            },
        },
            messages: {
                firstName: {
                    required: "Please enter the First name!"
                    },
                lastName: {
                    required: "Please enter the Last name!"
                },
                dob: {
                    required: "Please enter the Date of birth!"
                },
                mobile: {
                    required: "Please enter phone number",
                    maxlength: "Number must be at least 10 digit long",
                    remote: "Mobile already exists,Please try another"
                },
                age: {
                    required: "Please enter your age in digit"
                },
                email: {
                    required: "Please enter a valid email",
                    remote: "Email already exists,Please try another"
                },
                gender: {
                    required: "Please select a gender"
                },
                address1: {
                    required: "Please enter your address"
                },
            },
        });
    });
```

and here is my controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/addCustomer/checkemail",method= RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String checkEmail(HttpServletRequest req, Model model) {
    String email = req.getParameter("email");
    return service.findByEmail(email);
}

@RequestMapping(value="/addCustomer/checkmobile",method= RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String checkMobile(HttpServletRequest req, Model model) {
    String mobile = req.getParameter("mobile");
    return service.findByMobile(mobile);
}
```

Edit method in controller

```
@GetMapping("/editCustomer/{id}")
public ModelAndView editCustomer(@PathVariable("id") long id) throws Exception {
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
    Customer customer = service.getCustomerById(id);
    service.saveCustomer(customer);
    model.addObject("customerform", customer);
    model.setViewName("customer-form");
    return model;
}
```

I am using ModelAttribute to display the data in edit form. can anyone help out?